# Why do I get an error with any option used for python3 ttk checkbox?

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox

I have a checkbox that works fine with the defaults values:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.ttk import *

chk1 = Checkbutton(self , text=' 0 ', var=_Ch1_ ) 
chk1.grid(column=4, row=1)
```

When I try to add any option like "height = 5" I get the error:

_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-height"

*init*.py lione 2299

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  I expect that you've already compared your attempt with the appropriate on-line examples; we need to verify any repairs we suggest, using your original code.

Comment: Run this line `print(ttk.Checkbutton(self).keys())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `tkk.Checkbutton` does not support `height`. You might want to use normal `Checkbutton` instead of `ttk.Checkbutton`. In your example you've said `from ttk.tkinter import *` which means `ttk.Checkbutton` becomes `Checkbutton` but not same as `tk.Checkbutton`

But anyway keep in mind, this `height` option wont make the checkbutton bigger, itll just give space other widgets '10'(or whatever) pixels away from it, just like `pady`

[Read more](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Checkbutton.html)

Comment: thanks i saw that when I was looking up options. I seem to be confused on the difference between using  normal Checkbutton instead of ttk.Checkbutton? There is no direct call in the tkinter or ttk imports. I tried Michael Guidrys print and got : ['variable', 'onvalue', 'offvalue', 'command', 'takefocus', 'text', 'textvariable', 
'underline', 'width', 'image', 'compound', 'padding', 'state', 'cursor', 'style', 'class']

Comment: @user3005949 would appreciate marking it as the answer.

Comment: @user3005949 The thing is `ttk` belongs to `tkinter` too(`from tkinter import ttk`). The only real difference is the theme applied to it. `ttk` widgets look modern, while ordinary widgets looks `old`.

Comment: "But in the example youve used Checkbutton which shouldnt show an error." ... `from tkinter.ttk import *` ... it's a `ttk.Checkbutton`

Comment: @MichaelGuidry oh, i dint notice such a import there, thanks for telling, so if im not wrong, from `tkinter.ttk import *` will override `from tkinter import *`? Is that why checkbutton became `ttk`?

Comment: @CoolCloud - yes that's true, but that isn't what's happening here. Go look at their imports.